# How to download mysql database from server using command prompt in windows

Tags: mysql, windows, shell

I want to download **mysql** database from server using command prompt in windows.
I tried to use **ssh** to connect to the server.

But, it is not working. Is there any command to this?

Answer (score 1):

Exporting MySQL Data

This example shows you how to export a database. It is a good idea to export your data often as a backup.
Using SSH, execute the following command:

```
    mysqldump -p -u username database_name > dbname.sql
```

You will be prompted for a password, type in the password for the username and press Enter. Replace username, password and database_name with your MySQL username, password and database name.
The file dbname.sql now holds a backup of your database and is ready for download to your computer.

To export a single table from your database you would use the following command:

```
mysqldump -p --user=username database_name tableName > tableName.sql
```

Again you would need to replace the username, database and tableName with the correct information.
Once done the table specified would then be saved to your account as tableName.sql

Answer (score 0):

Have a look Backup or Schema/Data Comparison tools in [dbForge Studio for MySQL](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/). Command line and conencting through secure SSH connections are supported.